# Find the coefficient of $x^{17}$

Tags: probability, combinatorics, algebra-precalculus, statistics, contest-math

> Find the coefficient of $x^{17}$ in:$$ (1 + x^5 + x^7)^{20}$$

$x^{17} = x^{5} x^5 x^{7}$

I would say:

$$\frac{17!}{5!5!7!} $$

But this isnt the correct answer. I know I need to use combinations, just not sure how yet.

Comment: You have $20$ factors. From each you have to choose either $1$, $x^5$, or $x^7$. How many ways can you choose so that the product is $x^{17}$?

Comment: $\binom{20}{17,2,1}$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint**

As you correctly note, the only way the exponents add to 17 given your specific numbers is with two occurrences of $x^5$ and one occurrence of $x^7$.

Perhaps it will be easier to see what went wrong when we reword this a bit:

> Find the coefficient of $A^{17}B^2C^1$ in: $$(A+B+C)^{20}$$

In this case, $A=1$, $B=x^5$ and $C=x^7$, so $A^{17}B^2C^1=1^{17}(x^5)^2(x^7)^1=x^{17}$

Comment: So it is: $$20!/(17!2!1!) = 3420$$

Answer (score 1):

The only way to get $17$ adding $0$, $5$ and $7$ is $5+5+7$, so you need to choose $x^5$ in two factors, $x^7$ in one factor and $1$ elsewhere. The coeeficient will be the numbers of ways to choose two factors from $20$ times the number of ways to choose one factor from the remaining $18$:
$$\binom {20}2\cdot 18$$